# Json4s add JValue to JArray

Tags: arrays, json, scala, json4s

I'm using scala and Json4s to add a JValue to a JArray in a loop, this way:

```
    var recordsJArray = JArray
    for (record <- recordsList) {
       val mrecord= new com.google.gson.Gson().toJson(record.asMap())
       val jsonRecord = parse(mrecord)
       recordsJArray = recordsJArray.++jsonRecord
    }
```

I've searched de api: https://static.javadoc.io/org.json4s/json4s-core_2.9.1/3.0.0/org/json4s/JsonAST$$JArray.html

and I've tried to use the method:

```
 def ++ (other: JValue): JValue
```

But it's not working.

```
 error: value ++ is not a member of object org.json4s.JsonAST.JArray
[ERROR]         recordsJArray = recordsJArray++jsonRecord
```

Can someone please help me?
Is there any way of adding the JValue to the JArray?
Thank you

Comment: Looks like you are not using same version than the doc you've linked

Comment: Hello, I'm using scala-2.10 and the version for json4s is 3.5.1 from maven repository. I've just realized the link is for 2.9.1  https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.json4s/json4s-core_2.10/3.5.1

Comment: Great, you can now answer your own question by looking at the correct documentation!

Comment: I can't find any function like ++ in documentation, that's why I've kept the question. I guess the function doesn't exist in my version, so I still need help to solve it

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 1):

`++` returns `JValue`, which is a supertype of `JArray`.

Since `recordsJArray` must be a `JArray`, the Scala compiler is looking for an implementation of `++` that returns a `JArray`. Since there is none, the compiler reports that your desired function is not a member of the object on which you're trying to invoke it.

Instead of relying on JsonAST's function, you can steal [their implementation of `++` for your input types](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/fbe4b9a338812553b7211c3a9975f3f26e96424d/ast/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonAST.scala#L87) (JArray plus JValue):

```scala
recordsJArray = JArray(recordsJArray ::: List(jsonRecord))
```